# Why can Django request.user.is_authenticated take 8 seconds to execute?

Tags: python, django

I am utterly confused. A few days ago my Django app started working significantly slower.

It turned out that the following Django view takes

- **8** seconds to execute for an *authorized viewer*
- **0** seconds to execute for an *anonymous user*

```python
def speed_test(request):

    start = time.time() # measuring execution time 

    b = request.user.is_authenticated  # THIS somehow creates a problem

    response = {"test": "test"} # constructing a dummy response

    end = time.time() 
    logger.warning("speed test: " + str(end - start) + " auth = " + str(b)) # logging

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
```

```
17/Apr/2021 17:18:18 WARNING speed test: 8.06065821647644 auth = True
17/Apr/2021 17:23:04 WARNING speed test: 6.508827209472656e-05 auth = False
```

`is_authenticated` can be replaced by any function from `AbstractBaseUser` with the same results.
If I remove a call to `is_authenticated`, everything works fast for every user.

It is reproduced both with`runserver` and `gunicorn`/`uwsgi`.

But I can't reproduce it on my dev laptop, even connecting with the same remote database. So it doesn't look like a database issue, and it's definitely not a networking issue.

Django 3.08, python 3.8, ubuntu. Tried making a brand new venv - to no avail.

The DB connection is as default as it can be:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'user',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'hostname',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }

}
```

I would appreciate any hints on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Because for a real user `request.user.some_attr` will require to first load the user and thus make a database query. This can even result in first making a database connection if there are no connections in the pool.

Comment: Was going to comment the same.

Comment: I assume you are using a postgreSQL database?

Comment: You can disable server-side cursors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#transaction-pooling-and-server-side-cursors and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG = True`? Each request is served by a new thread in that case so this would happen in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Django lazy loads request.user so that it can be either User or AnonymousUser depending on the authentication state. It only "wakes up" and returns the appropriate class when an attribute is accessed on it. In this case, we are calling `is_authenticated` attribute and now it has to make a call to database to check. It's highly likely that the query to db is taking a long time in your case.

Comment: `.is_authenticated` has been changed to an attribute since Django-1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is a lazy property. That means that Django will *not* fetch the logged in user object, unless you really need it.

If you thus use `request.user.is_authenticated` then this will require making a query to the database to fetch the user object. If there is no session with the logged in user, then retrieving `request.user` is fast, since it will not even make a query to the database: if the session data for the session id is missing, it will simply return the `AnonymousUser` object.

This can even be worse if that is the *first* query that the system makes, since then there are no open connections, and thus it can require extra logic to first make a connection to the database. Especially PostgreSQL is known to be quite expensive in opening connections.

Django will normally make use of a *connection pool* of open connections, and reuse connections for new queries. But if this is thus the first query, the pool is normally empty, and thus it will require some effort to open the connection and make a query.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that this happens on every request, not just on the first one. Only authed users can access views that access DB. I logged out every user to make sure that they don't affect the performance. But it didn't help. Is there a way to increase the number of connections in the pool to see if it makes things better?

Comment: @AlexeyKalmykov: can you edit the question and show the `DATABASE` settings?

Comment: Sure, added the connection settings - it's default postresql.